# Using JQuery To Access A Data Service/API Across Domains

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to access a 3rd party api over http using jquery .ajax (or .get, .post etc). The api resides on my machine at

```
http://localhost:7777/server/<method>?<args>
```

The server has a stack of methods to query its OLAP server such as login (which returns a login key to use with other methods), databases (that lists the databases on the server), cubes, dimensions etc etc

for example

To login to the server

http://localhost:7777/server/login?user=admin&password=21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3

If I enter this into a browser address bar, I get the correct data back.

However, I want to make a small web page to test the calls and figured I should be able to use jQuery to create the Gets and return the data that went to the browser.

Heres my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Palo Test Report</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">            
        function calculate(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"http://localhost:7777/server/login?user=admin&password=21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3&callback=?",
                success: function(data,textStatus){
                    alert(data + ":" + textStatus);
                }
                ,
                error: function(request,errorStatus,errorThrown){
                    alert("Error:" + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
  <body>
      <div>Sample Palo Report #1</div>
      <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The method goes of to the server and hits the success callback. However, the data paramter is an empty string.

I read a few posts regarding problems with cross domain access via ajax and it looks like thats what might be happening as the service is running off a different port, though I'm a bit surprised with the "success" flag. Another odd thing is that if I create a new virtual dir in IIS and drop the file in there, I hit the error callback with an empty errorThrown parameter.

The service/api is returning simple strings not json so getJSON doesn't work.

Is what I am trying possible with jQuery?

I do have a workaround but its pretty ugly!

Thanks in advance

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax calls are limited on the same domain. You need jsonP to query an 3rd party domain. Check [ajax()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) method **jsonP** option.

**UPDATE**

[CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/acc) (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is also present as working draft from w3c.

Comment: This is no longer true. Most people would consider both `JSONP` and `CORS` to be Ajax calls. Both require support from the server.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is your test webpage is located on *http://localhost:7777* because it wouldn't work otherwise.

*$.ajax* works as expected but since you didn't provide the option *dataType: "jsonp"*:

- it assumes the data retrieved is *XML* or *HTML* (an "intelligent" guess according to the doc, but we all know what intelligence really means when it comes to algorithms)
- it doesn't bother handling the *callback=?* piece of the url (if you trace network traffic with something like firebug, you can easily control that the *callback=?* part of the url stays as is)

Now, the server response is definitely not *XML* nor *HTML*, but the request succeeded. So you end up with your success callback being called with an empty data parameter (though I would have expected a basic *HTML* document with the response text in its body).

Just add *dataType: "jsonp"* in your options and it should work as expected.